# XML Encoding for French and german characters

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I'm trying to copy some text to xml file.
The problem is that all special characters are converted to symbols..
I googled and tested tons of codes but no help so far

I would like to copy a text file that contains the following line

```
<data path="Procédures de support/Achat" name="Gestion dös achats et dés magasins" type="Main Process"  />
```

however if i use encoding to text file, it works, but if i want to create xml then it doesn't

Here is my code:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath,Encoding.Default)) // I also tested Encoding.UTF8
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileOutput,settings))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument(false);
                    writer.WriteStartElement(startRoot);

                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteRaw(line);
                    }

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the file you're reading in contains characters encoded in UTF-8 (Encoding.Default).

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is *not* UTF-8, even though the default encoding for XML is Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow it worked when i changed the encoding to

```
encoding="Windows-1252"
```